# Re position the item in an array based on the index order given in another array

Tags: java, c#, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays as below.

```
string[] alb = new string[5] 
             {
                "B","Z","C", "E","T"
             };
int[] orderedIndexes = {0,3,4,1,2}
```

Based on the indexes given in second array I would like to align the items in the first array. I don't want to use another array as buffer and like to use the same array for swapping the items. The result am expecting is like

```
alb = {"B","E","T","Z","C"}.
```

Note : As the real problem is having real business values I cannot post the homework I did.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check if that index array is a valid index array like this:

```
var isValidIndex = !Enumerable.Range(0, alb.Length - 1).Except(orderedIndexes).Any();
```

Then you can simply use the `Select` on the `orderedIndexes` like this:

```
var result = orderedIndexes.Select(i => alb[i]).ToArray();

//result: {"B","E","T","Z","C"}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution as I got from you :) as below  alb = orderedIndexes.Select(i => alb[i]).ToArray();

Comment: This creates a new array though and the requirements stated "I don't want to use another array as buffer and like to use the same array for swapping the items.".

Answer (score 3):

The linq answer is absolutely great, but I thought it would be fun to solve it in an old-school array manipulation way.  Besides, part of the question mentioned not creating a buffer, which to me, the linq answer violates somewhat. Anyway, for what it's worth...

```
using System;

namespace x
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var alb = new[] { "B","Z","C","E","T" };
            int[] orderedIndexes = {2,0,1,4,3};

            for (var i = 0; i < orderedIndexes.Length; i++)
            {
                var x = orderedIndexes[i];
                var ts = alb[i];
                alb[i] = alb[x];
                alb[x] = ts;
                x = Array.IndexOf(orderedIndexes, i);
                var ti = orderedIndexes[i];
                orderedIndexes[i] = orderedIndexes[x];
                orderedIndexes[x] = ti;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < orderedIndexes.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", i, alb[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you tried but it failed for the following -->
var alb = new[] { "B","Z","C","E","T" };
int[] orderedIndexes = {4, 3, 1, 2, 0}; Becuase of the sortedindexes are no more valid when we swap the items in the array.

Comment: This is almost correct, but you forget to assign `orderedIndexes[i]` in the swap. After correcting that, this is actually the answer to the OP's question, since it solves it in place.

Comment: Whoops, you are correct @classic_vmk. Perhaps I should have written a unit test :).

Comment: Okay, I believe it should work now. The swap on the index took me a minute to get correct!

Comment: Thats the same solution I also implemented.. :)